# I must now take hold myself

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms-in-context

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_16)

Passage 252

> There was yet one more postscript, yet one more outburst of self-pity and pathetic adjuration; and a doctor's opinion, unpromising enough, was besides enclosed. I pass them both in silence. I think shame to have shown, at so great length, the half-baked virtues of my friend dissolving in the crucible of sickness and distress; and the effect upon my spirits can be judged already. I got to my feet when I had done, drew a deep breath, and stared hard at Honolulu. One moment the world seemed at an end; the next, I was conscious of a rush of independent energy. On Jim I could rely no longer; I must now **take hold myself**. I must decide and act on my own better thoughts.

I know what *take hold* means . . .  (Collins has this: take hold
PHRASE
If something takes hold, it gains complete control or influence over a person or thing.
She felt a strange excitement taking hold of her. [+ of]
She was determined not to let the illness take hold again.)

. . . but *take hold myself* doesn't really work here in my opinion. What do you take *take hold myself* to mean in this context? Is there a synonym?

Comment: I, myself, must take hold.  The text glosses what is meant in the very next sentence.

Comment: A synonmous expression would be "I must *seize* control".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence means that the speaker had to stop looking to Jim for help and instead accept responsibility himself to take the problem(s) in hand and resolve it (or them) on his own.

What he’s taking hold of is the problems. The authors’ omitting the complement is analogous to leaving out “for my own fate” from the sentence “I must accept the responsibility myself.” Or to omitting “of the situation” from “The children are creating havoc, so I must take charge.”

Comment: Great help! Thank you very much indeed; especially that you mentioned the omission of the complement clarifies the issue.